# WooCommerce - Add product urls to dropdown values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I am trying to add a select which displays all products. I am using the following code:

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">

    <option value="">- Select Value - </option>
    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
            $loop->the_post();
            echo '<option value="#">'.the_title('','',false).'</option>';
        endwhile;
    ?>

</select>
```

This works but I am unable to find a way to also add the product link to the option value.

I have tried the standard permalink code and

```
$url = get_permalink( $product_id );
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: where did you got $product_id ? inside you loop there is nothing like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here to get the Product Id is:

```
$product_id = $loop->post->ID;
```

So the code to get the product URL could be:

```
$product_id = $loop->post->ID; // Product ID
$product = wc_get_product($product_id); // WC_Product object (instance)
$product_link = $product->get_permalink( );
```

Or

```
$product_id = $loop->post->ID; // Product ID
$product_link = get_permalink( $product_id );
```

So your final code should be:

```html
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">

    <option value="">- Select Value - </option>
    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
            $loop->the_post();
            $post_id = $loop->post->ID;
            $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
            $link = get_permalink( $post_id );
            $title = $product->get_name();
            echo '<option value="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</option>';
        endwhile;

        // Reset post data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>

</select>
```